# How do I re-write this DOS command without using the PIPE symbol?

Tags: batch-file, dos, windows-task-scheduler

I use this command to verify if a particular schedule task exists:

```
schtasks.exe | findstr /I /c:TaskName
```

I need to write something that DOES NOT use the PIPE "|" so I tried this:

```
schtasks.exe /Query /TN TaskName
```

but it only works for Windows 2008, not Windows 2003 machines since the `/TN` option is not available in 2003.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Heh, yeah.  `schtasks /query >tmpfile && findstr /i /c:"Taskname" tmpfile` doesn't use a pipe.  `:>`

Comment: Simply put it in a `for /f` loop!

Comment: rojo, that was genius. Thank you!

Comment: how do I mark this as Answered by rojo? can't find it anywhere in the UI :(

Comment: @rojo Make your comment an answer.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid the pipe? are you trying to process the output of `FINDSTR` in a `FOR/F` ? If so, perhaps `^|` in place of `|` will solve your problem...

Comment: @PeterWright - I wondered that, too.  But if that were the case, he would've been no better off using `&&` or `>`.  I bet he wants to use it in some sort of in-house job file, like a to-do list in a csv file delimited with pipes.  \*shrug\*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, yeah.

```
schtasks /query >tmpfile && findstr /i /c:"Taskname" tmpfile
```

doesn't use a pipe. `:>`